# Is there any Blender Plugin that opens .max file?

Tags: file-format

Is there any Blender Plugin that opens .max file? I am not looking for any Bridge Plugin cause I cannot afford Autodesk 3ds Max. It would be a great help if someone suggested me a solution thank you.

Comment: You could download 3ds max trial version for free

Comment: .max is the binary file format, no chance to open that in any other DCC/tool.

Comment: I have seen some website which can convert Max to FBX if somehow they manage to do that, I thought the Blender community might already create something for this. I also know that .max is a native file format for 3DS Max but Blender Comunity always surprises me with extraordinary things.  Anyway, maybe I got too spoiled and expecting too much. :) thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: No problem. Most likely because they *pay for it* and using its commandline to convert to FBX. Why you can not "open" the max file: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file